# import cv2 ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 Allready have checked related posts

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, opencv, windows-10, anaconda

I'm currently working on getting cv2 ready for Python 3.5.4, Anaconda 4.2.0 and Eclipse 64bit OS is Windows 10. I'm getting the discribed error and tried to fix it using other stackoverflow posts like installing 32bit Version eg. x84 cv2.pyd which hasn't worked.

I downloaded the newest version from opencv 3.3.0 also tried 3.2.0 on http://opencv.org/releases.html.

I copied the file:

"\opencv\build\python\2.7\x64\cv2.pyd"

into Anaconda site-packege folder additionally added the link of the opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll to my PATH variable.

When I now write:

> > import cv2
> >
> > cv2.imread("RANDOMPATH") and compile I get the described error

I also tried to install the cv2 lib using opencv_running:

> > pip install python-3.3.0.10-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

I didn't get an error but I have not a single method when I call cv2. in my Code.

I tried to install also in order to get more moduls but run in the following Error:

> > pip install C:\Users\Max\Downloads\opencv_python-3.3.0+contrib-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

ERROR:
opencv_python-3.3.0+contrib-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Are there any suggestions that might help. Please comment a detailed answer since I usually not realy used to install libs in Python. Thank you in advance! Best Max

Comment: Also installed C:\Users\...\Downloads\opencv_python-3.3.0+contrib-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the whole stuff - *Python 3.6* as well as *OpenCV*. Now everything works out. Don't know another solution